# Android animation scaling up

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation

I have a `custom_view` with the following layout:

```
 <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/wrapper_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/letter"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textAlignment="center" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

I then want to scale this view up using the following code:

```
ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(custom_view, "scaleX", 1, sizeTo / sizeFrom);
ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(custom_view, "scaleY", 1, sizeTo / sizeFrom);
```

The scaling up is working, however, the view and the letter gets all blurry.
What am I doing wrong here? (scaling down is working fine).